# Setting cookies during development using localhost with Google Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, cookies

I am creating a microservice web application. For session persistence I am using JSON Web Tokens (JWT). For development, each microservice is running on localhost:{PORTNUMBER}. I would like to store these JWT's in a cookie on the client-side. Further, I would like the cookie to be stored via the set-cookie response header from my server (as opposed to sending the JWT to the client and then storing it via client side scripts). I am building my server with basic node/express.

I am having a problem getting the cookie to actually store on the browser side. I know the header is being created correctly because I can see the meta data is received on the browser side. From my research, this problem has to do with the fact that I am developing using localhost. All of the solutions I have read have suggested that changing the /etc/hosts file on my machine from localhost to anything with two "dots" in it, ie dev.localhosts.com, should work. It is not working. I suspect this is a localhost problem, but it is also possible it has something to do with the ports I am using for each microservice.

Comment: Did the `domain` part of the Set-Cookie header match the actual two dot hostname you used?

Comment: yes, I tried it with dev.localhosts.com and .localhosts.com